# Grails - Can Jobs be disabled using config.groovy

Tags: grails, jobs, config

I'm wondering if there is a way to disable jobs using config.groovy or by some other means. I've seen posts where you can disable plugins via config.groovy, but haven't seen anything about jobs. I'd like to be able to either disable all jobs, or disable each job individually without having to comment them out. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

As the triggers are defined as a static member in a job, you can override these in `Config.groovy`. You can also therefore remove the triggers for a particular job in configuration, thereby disabling it:

### MyJob.groovy

```
class MyJob {

  static triggers = {
    simple name: 'mySimpleTrigger', startDelay: 60000, repeatInterval: 1000  
  }    

  def execute() { 
    // Job code goes here
    // This method won't get called using the configuration below
  }
}
```

### Config.groovy

```
MyJob.triggers = {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is by far better than introducing a new variable for every job to check.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you use Quartz plugin. In this case you can disable it via Config.groovy

```
quartz {
    autoStartup = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following would effectively disable each job (though this is not exactly the same as disabling the Quartz plugin completely):

### Config.groovy

```
MyJob.diabled = true
MyOtherJob.disabled = false
```

### MyJob.groovy

```
class MyJob {

  def grailsApplication

  static triggers = {
    simple name: 'mySimpleTrigger', startDelay: 60000, repeatInterval: 1000  
  }    

  def execute() { 
    String className = getClass().simpleName

    if (grailsApplication.config."$className".disabled) {
      return
    }
    // Job code goes here
  }
}
```

To avoid repeating the code above in each Job class either put in into an abstract base class (or use metaprogramming to achieve the same result without inheritance).